# Slide Menu IOS Using aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, background-color

I am trying to change Navigation bar background color in viewDidLoad using the same example in the link below but that's not working.
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];`

please help.

https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]To change the NAv bar color, You have to use bar tint color:

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor=[UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: ok , let me try you code. you want the color change for top nav bar or slide nav bar ?

Comment: where are you applying the color? In whihc method?

Comment: I am putting the code in viewDidLoad at HomeViewController but it is not working

Comment: the color becoming light with new xcode version is that a way to make them dark or I have to use image for background?

Comment: try to use gradient colors, or darkgreen color. If nothing works , you can go for image

Comment: I 'm using colorwithRGB, i know nothing about gradient color but i will research. thanks for helping